# HttpAddUrl returns with error ERR_INVALID_NETNAME

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, httpapi

I'm creating a HTTP server by doing the following:

```
retCode = HttpInitialize( 
            HttpApiVersion,
            HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER,    // Flags
            NULL                       // Reserved
            );

retCode = HttpCreateHttpHandle(
            &hReqQueue,        // Req Queue
            0                  // Reserved
            );

retCode = HttpAddUrl(
            hReqQueue,          // Req Queue
            localUrl.c_str(),   // Fully qualified URL
            NULL                // Reserved
            );
```

`localUrl` would be something like `http://192.168.1.x/someUrl` or `http://37.123.43.x/someUrl`. The base URL obviously doesn't change in between adding Urls.

`HttpInitialize` and `HttpCreateHttpHandle` return success. However, `HttpAddUrl` returns with error 1214 (ie. `ERR_INVALID_NETNAME`) when I use a non-local IP address. I'm starting the program as an administrator.

What can the problem be?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you cannot bind to the wildcard hostname `+`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: `http://+/someUrl` matches `/someUrl` regardless of the interface on which the request arrives.